# Using JavaFX 8 Scene, Read Keyboard Input while running

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent, keycode, scene

I have my JavaFX 8 Scene going nicely. Now, while everything else is happening, I would like to continuously check for any KeyEvent/KeyCode while the program is running. I have a Timeline called timeline set to INDEFINITE and I've set my cycle count to indefinite with

```
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

I'm looking for an easy method that is also clean and won't make my program choppy.

Comment: Why do you need a `TimeLine` for listening to `KeyEvents`?

Comment: I'm doing animations, that's all I have so far. I now want to be able to do stuff like, restart the animation, or display a button on the screen, or anything else, based on user input from keys. I only mentioned it because I was worried about interruptions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) listener to listen to when key is [pressed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KEY_PRESSED), [release](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KEY_RELEASED), [typed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED) or [any](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#ANY) of them. It doesn't matter what you have running on other threads, whether that's some infinite loop, or anything else; if the user presses a button, the listener will be called.

You just need to add a [listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to the scene and the key event which you want to listen to.

```
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> {
      if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {
          System.out.println("You pressed enter");
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, ItachiUchiha!

Comment: I guess you mean "it doesn't matter"?